# How to set MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN in convertAndSend method in rabbitmq?

Tags: reactjs, spring, rabbitmq, stomp

I try to persists and save messages in rabbitmq queue.

This is my controller in Spring

```java
    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;


    private final static String CHAT_EXCHANGE_NAME = "chat.exchange";
    private final static String CHAT_QUEUE_NAME = "chat.queue";
    private final static String CHAT_TOPIC = "amq.topic";

 @MessageMapping("chat.message.{roomId}")
    public void send(MessageDto messageDto, @DestinationVariable String roomId) {
        System.out.println(roomId);
        System.out.println("message"+messageDto.getRoomId());
        System.out.println(messageDto.getContent());


        //rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(CHAT_TOPIC, "room." + roomId, messageDto, message -> {
            message.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
            return message;
        });

    }
```

and this is react code

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    stompClient.connect('guest', 'guest',()=> {
      console.log("rabbitmq connected")
        stompClient.subscribe(`/topic/room.3`,(data) => {
        //stompClient.subscribe(`/exchange/chat.exchange/room.${roomId}`,(data) => {
        //stompClient.subscribe("/exchange/chat.exchange/room.2",(data) => {
        console.log("this roomId",roomId)
        const newMessage : message = JSON.parse(data.body) as message;
        addMessage(newMessage);
      },{'auto-delete':true, 'durable':true, 'exclusive':false});
    });
  },[contents]);

  const handleEnter = (roomId: string, content: string) => {
    const newMessage: message = { roomId, content };
    stompClient.send(`/pub/chat.message.2`, 
    {'messageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN':true},JSON.stringify(newMessage));
    //stompClient.send("/pub/chat.message.2", {},JSON.stringify(newMessage));
    console.log("thismessage",newMessage)
    console.log("roomId", roomId)
    setMessage("");
  };
```

I want to sustain my message when my client page even refresh.
So I googled and found that set MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN,
you can get message when reconnect your queue.
so I set the configuration but it seems doesn't work

where do i have to fix it?

and i try to use "topic" in rabbitmq and each client has their own queue

so when some client connect with my server they have their own queue.